# Почему не работает setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Всем привет, решил немного декорировать код и написал такую замечательную (нерабочую) функцию

```
function interval(o){
        var i = 0,
            count = o.count || 1,
            timeout = o.timeout || 1000,
            start = o.startFunc || function(){},
            end = o.endFunc || function(){};
        var timer = setTimeout(function tick(){
            i++;
            if(i < count){
                start(i);
                setTimeout(tick, timeout);
            } else{
                clearTimeout(timer);
                end();
            }
        }, timeout);
    }
```

Вот попытка её запустить:

```
interval({
      count: 100,
      timeout: function(){return getRandomInt(5, 15)*10;},
      startFunc: function(count){
                $('#analyze').width(count+'%');
                $('#analyze-text > span').text(count+'%');
           },
      endFunc: function(){
                $('#computing').css('display', 'none');
                $('#finish-screen').fadeIn(600);
           }
      });
```

Проблема в том, что setTimeout() не срабатывает. Скажите, почему?

Comment: Тот случай когда нужна типизация... Какой тип должен быть у переменной timeout? А вы что туда передали?

Comment: `setTimeout` у вас работает. Наверное, вам надо изменить вопрос. Почему он срабатывает, не учитывая параметр `timeout`?

Comment: В дополнение к проблеме передачи `timeout`: переменная `timer` и вызов `clearTimeout` тут лишние. А ещё стоит подумать, действительно ли при `count = 10` функция `startFunc` должна вызываться всего `9` раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Дело в том, что мне действительно нужно передать функцию в переменную timeout, но при использовании функции setTimeout() вторым аргументом я передал лишь ссылку на функцию, в то время как ожидал, что она выполнится. Вот рабочий вариант.

```
function interval(o){
    var i = 0,
        count = o.count || 1,
        timeout = o.timeout || 1000,
        start = o.start || function(){},
        end = o.end || function(){};
        function tick(){
            i++;
            if(typeof(o.timeout) == 'function'){
                timeout = o.timeout();
            }
            if(i <= count){
                start(i);
                setTimeout(tick, timeout);
            } else{
                end();
            }
        }
        setTimeout(tick, timeout);
}
```